# Moq a function with anonymous type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, anonymous-function, anonymous-types

I'm trying to mock this method

```
Task<TResult> GetResultAsync<TResult>(Func<string, TResult> transformFunc)
```

like this

```
iMock.Setup(m => m.GetResultAsync(It.IsAny<Func<string, object>>())).ReturnsAsync(new { isPair = false });
```

The method to test doing the call passing an anonymous type to the generic parameter like this

```
instance.GetResultAsync(u => new {isPair = u == "something" }) //dont look at the function return because as generic could have diferent implementations in many case
```

Moq never matches my GetResultAsync method with the parameters sent.

I'm using Moq 4

Comment: Not sure... but using Setup for this purpose may not be correct.  If you have created the anonymous object in your unit test `var testObject = { whatevs }` you can skip the setup and verify it at the end `iMock.Verify(x => x.GetResultAsync(testObject))`.  I believe this should work as expected.

Comment: How do you want the mock to behave? you are not specifying anything.

Comment: Will and Yacoub thanks for your interest. I updated my question with the return of this mocked method. @Will, I need to mock the behavior of the method because it's going to be used inside another method I'm testing

Comment: As a heads up, this won't work without some extra effort. You can't create an anonymous object, and use it in another project. I ran into [an issue doing the same thing last year](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29755234/1195056).

Comment: One possible solution is to tell the mocking framework to return an object that you create via reflection of type `TResult` and that you have set its `isPair` property via reflection to `false`. I am not sure if this can be done with Moq, but it can be done with FakeItEasy. It is a complex solution but it should work. Let me know if it is in option for you to use FakeItEasy and I will post a solution.

Comment: I posted this as an issue over at Moq's issue tracker: [`moq/moq4#552`](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/552). Matching objects of anonymous types looks like something that *should* work; I'll look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anonymous type is going to cause you problems. You need a concrete type for this to work.

The following example worked when I changed

```
instance.GetResultAsync(u => new {isPair = u == "something" })
```

to

```
instance.GetResultAsync(u => (object) new {isPair = u == "something" })
```

Moq is unable to match the anonymous type and that is why you get `null` when called.

```
[TestClass]
public class MoqUnitTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Moq_Function_With_Anonymous_Type() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = new { isPair = false };

        var iMock = new Mock<IService>();
        iMock.Setup(m => m.GetResultAsync(It.IsAny<Func<string, object>>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(expected);

        var consumer = new Consumer(iMock.Object);

        //Act   
        var actual = await consumer.Act();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    public interface IService {
        Task<TResult> GetResultAsync<TResult>(Func<string, TResult> transformFunc);
    }

    public class Consumer {
        private IService instance;

        public Consumer(IService service) {
            this.instance = service;
        }

        public async Task<object> Act() {
            var result = await instance.GetResultAsync(u => (object)new { isPair = u == "something" });
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

if the code calling the `GetResultAsync` is dependent on using the anonymous type then what you are trying to do with your test wont work with your current setup. You would probably need to provide a concrete type to the method.

```
[TestClass]
public class MoqUnitTest {

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Moq_Function_With_Concrete_Type() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = new ConcreteType { isPair = false };

        var iMock = new Mock<IService>();
        iMock.Setup(m => m.GetResultAsync(It.IsAny<Func<string, ConcreteType>>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(expected);

        var sut = new SystemUnderTest(iMock.Object);

        //Act   
        var actual = await sut.MethodUnderTest();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    class ConcreteType {
        public bool isPair { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IService {
        Task<TResult> GetResultAsync<TResult>(Func<string, TResult> transformFunc);
    }

    public class SystemUnderTest {
        private IService instance;

        public SystemUnderTest(IService service) {
            this.instance = service;
        }

        public async Task<object> MethodUnderTest() {
            var result = await instance.GetResultAsync(u => new ConcreteType { isPair = u == "something" });
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```