# How do I mock generic with Func parameter with moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq

I have a method that I want to test for generic repository:

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync<TEntity>(
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = null,
            int? skip = null,
            int? take = null)
            where TEntity : class, IEntity
        {
            return await GetQueryable<TEntity>(null, orderBy, includeProperties, skip, take).ToListAsync();
        }
```

I am clueless how to mock this with moq.

Comment: What did you try so far? Are there any errors that you are getting?

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416561/moq-a-function-with-anonymous-type

Comment: _repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync<Program>(null, null, null, null)).Returns() i am not sure what to return.

Comment: _repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync<Program>(It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>>>(), null, null, null)).ReturnsAsync(). This is what the response to the question that I posted suggests.

Comment: ok got it like this:             _repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync(It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Program>, IOrderedQueryable<Program>>>()‌,
                null, null, null)).ReturnsAsync(new List<Program>());